# Kivy get iDevice and Android ID

Tags: android, ios, kivy

I'm contemplating writing an app that I'd like to make for iOS and Android, and I want to use Kivy since I can write once, perform some magic, and deploy to iOS and Android. My plan is to have the program connect to a server which will return profile, but I'd need to link each profile to its device. Does Kivy have a way of getting the device ID, or is there a better method of making linking profiles to devices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This functionality is included in [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer), a kivy sister-project providing a pythonic cross-platform api to different features. You would get the id with `plyer.uniqueid.id`.

You can also check the code ([ios](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/plyer/platforms/ios/uniqueid.py), [android](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/plyer/platforms/android/uniqueid.py)) for how plyer implements this with kivy's pyjnius and pyobjus projects that let you directly call java and objc from python. In this case, both are very simple.